# error: 'class TermPaper' has no member named ''

Tags: c++

I'm creating a small source file/project for class and I keep receiving the errors 'class TermPaper' has no member named 'setfirstName'/'setlastName'/'setsubject' ' etc. Basically every line with .set or .get is an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TermPaper.cpp"
#include "TermPaper.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //Declare variables
    TermPaper paper1;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string subject;
    char grade;

    cout << "Please enter first name. " << endl;

    cin >> firstName;

    cout << "Please enter last name." << endl;

    cin >> lastName;

    cout << "Please enter subject." << endl;

    cin >> subject;

    cout << "Please enter letter grade." << endl;

    cin >> grade;

    paper1.setfirstName();
    paper1.setlastName();
    paper1.setsubject();
    paper1.setgrade();

    cout << "First name:" << paper1.getfirstName() << endl;

    cout << "Last Name: " << paper1.getLastName() << endl;

    cout << "Subject: " << paper1.getSubject() << endl;

    cout << "Grade: " << paper1.getGrade() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is the .cpp file I created, and below is the .cpp file I was given by my instructor and told to copy into the project folder that has my code above inside. This is where I assume the class TermPaper was defined, and I'm not confident enough to edit it since I'm afraid I'll just generate more errors.

```
TermPaper::TermPaper( )
{
  fName = "";
  lName = "";
  subject = "";
  letterGrade = 'F';
}
void TermPaper::setFName(string fN)
{
   fName = fN;
}
void TermPaper::setLName(string lN)
{
  lName = lN;
}
void TermPaper::setSubject(string sub)
{
  subject = sub;
}
void TermPaper::setLetterGrade(char grade)
{
  letterGrade = grade;
}
string  TermPaper::getFName( )
{
  return fName;
}
string TermPaper::getLName( )
{
  return lName;
}
string TermPaper::getSubject( )
{
  return subject;
}
char TermPaper::getLetterGrade( )
{
  return letterGrade;
}
```

I'm not quite sure if there was an error with the file my instructor gave me ( there weren't any detected from the compiler ) or if I am just forgetting something in my own code. I've been looking through my textbooks for the past hour now, and all of the examples are telling me nothing.

any help would be great, especially since this my second to last assignment for the semester!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include of the cpp file pointed out by Michael Albers is a definite no-no that will bring much grief, but...

But I don't see `setfirstName` among the methods of `TermPaper` in the posted snippet. Try calling the `setFName` method that is provided by `TermPaper`, and don't forget that you need to provide the method's required parameters. Without the parameters the poor compiler has no clue what you are trying to do. It will look for a function that looks like `void TermPaper::setFName()`* and not find one.

```
paper1.setFName(firstName);
paper1.setLName(lastName);
paper1.setSubject(subject);
paper1.setLetterGrade(grade);
```

* this is not quite true. It will look for something that looks like `TermPaper::setFName()` with any return type. Overloading is always based on the parameters and doesn't give a darn about the return type.

Comment: `setsubject` and `setgrade` aren't defined in `TermPaper` either. They seem to be `setSubject` and `setLetterGrade`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much! It compiled correctly. I guess I glossed over the names for those lines, my bad.

Comment: Hey, I did the same thing with `setsubject` and `setgrade` when I wrote my answer. Thank @computerfreaker for spotting that. Read and apply Michael Alber's answer as well. It will save you no small amount of future grief.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the include of the .cpp file. Typically you just include the .h file and the .cpp file is compiled into its own separate object file (.o). Then all the .o files are linked together into the executable. In you case, you could probably get away with including the function bodies into your source file, but they need to be after the include of the .h otherwise the compiler doesn't know what that class "looks like" (i.e., the definition of the class).